# Склоняется ли слово "розацеа"

Tags: склонение

Ув. филологи! Склоняется ли слово "розацеа"?

Маска для кожи с розацеа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы не сказала, что вариант "розацея" неправильный. Да, по-латыни так пишется, но мы так не говорим. Иначе тогда надо было бы говорить, например, "Мариа", а не "Мария".

Answer (score 3):

Слово "розацеа" не склоняется.

Вообще говоря, заимствованные слова могут склоняться только в том случае, когда их структура подходит под одно из склонений. В нашем случае слово оканчивается на гласные ЕА, что нехарактерно для русских слов.

Отметим, что розацеа (другое название – розовые угри) иногда неправильно называют "розацея", и вот это слово могло бы склоняться, сравнить: панацея - панацеей.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (о правильности названия):

Вариант "розацеа" встречается намного чаще, в том числе в медицинских журналах. Возможно, "розацею" можно считать разговорным вариантом. Огорчает, что иногда оба слова встречаются в одном источнике: "розацеа" как нач. форма, а "розацея" в косвенных падежах.

http://www.eurofemme.ru/lib/rosacea.php - этот источник утверждает, что розацея - это неправильно.

http://www.centrplastiki.ru/o_rosacea_s01.html - этот источник утверждает следующее:"Заболевание правильнее называть розацеа (от латинского rosaceus - розовый), поскольку используемые раннее термины «розовые угри» или «acne rosacea» не соответствуют истинной морфологии сущности розацеа".